# Glasswire alternative for Ubuntu?

Tags: security

When I was using Windows, one of my favorite apps was Glasswire so I could see every bit of data that my machine was sending and receiving and which apps were doing so. Is there a application that is similar to this? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like _wireshark_ perhaps?

Comment: You assume we know what "Glasswire" is/does. We don't.

Comment: Here's the official website, https://www.glasswire.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tcpdump** if you want a lightweight, console only program.

**Wireshark** if you want a full fledged GUI, which can visualize and filter dumps from tcpdump, or capture all by itself.

**Nethogs** seems to be able to give you a per process network usage, though I never tried it. I think this should be the closest one to glasswire.

Comment: Yes, I've used Wireshark before. However what I'm specifically looking for something that specifically shows what apps or services are sending data without having to dig deep to see that info.

Comment: Then nethogs is your tool

Comment: It's sure does the job and it's command line based, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link for GUI version of Nethogs, [Nethogs-QT](https://slist.lilotux.net/linux/nethogs-qt/index_en.html).